# Concat downloaded content by wget

Tags: bash

I want to get the latest release of certain package. In order to do so I did this:

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE -O /tmp/chromedriver_release
wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`cat /tmp/chromedriver_release`/chromedriver_linux64.zip -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

- There's not a direct link to the latest version (at least none that I could find)
- This instructions are part of a provisioning script, I don't have curl installed and I don't want to install it

I checked wget arguments and I didn't find anything that allows me to redirect the downloaded content to stdout. Will this be my best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very hard to read like that.
The duplication of the same base url is also not great.

With the `-O` flag, you could specify `-` to make the output go to `stdout`.

Lastly, `` `...` `` is obsolete syntax, use the modern `$(...)` instead.

```
baseurl=https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
filename=chromedriver_linux64.zip

version=$(wget "$baseurl"/LATEST_RELEASE -O-)
wget "$baseurl/$version/$filename" -O "/tmp/$filename"
```